# parsing the word from the string using strtok

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(){
        int n1,n2;
        char* str = malloc(1000);
        char* str1,*str2;
        fgets(str,1000,stdin);
        printf("\n str : %s \n",str);
        str1 = strtok(str," ");
        str2 = strtok(NULL," ");
        if(NULL == str1 || NULL == str2){
                printf("\n str1 and str2 are NULL \n");
                return 0;
        }
        n1 = strlen(str1);
        n2 = strlen(str2);
        printf("\n n1 :  %d n2 : %d \n",n1,n2);
        printf("\n str1 : %s str2 : %s \n",str1,str2);
        return 0;
}
```

The second string str2 is preceeded by a space before if the i/p is entered as below,
qwe  qwe[Enter]
3 4

If tried like this with a space before pressing the enter I get the correct string and the string length.
Here is the sample output,
qwe qwe[a space and enter]
3 3

How to eliminate the space and print the correct string length

Comment: use `str2 = strtok(NULL," \n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` retains the new-line character at the end of an input line, so your string is `"qwe qwe\n"`. There are many ways to fix this. Here are two:

You can remove the new-line with `strtok` after the `fgets`, exploiting the fact that `strtok` replaces the separators with null-charaters:

```
fgets(str,1000,stdin);
strtok(str, "\n");            // str has no trailing new line
```

Or you could specify the new-line character as additional separator in your `strtok` calls:

```
str1 = strtok(str," \n");
str2 = strtok(NULL," \n");
```